# How is my light attached to the ceiling?

Tags: lighting

How in the world is this attached to the ceiling? Does anyone know what my next step should be?

I tried turning the circle piece in the middle counter clockwise but the chandelier didn’t come loose, it just kept turning.

[image]

Comment: Normally the center is threaded through a yoke. If it doesn't come loose I would suspect the yoke has stripped and a nut above the yoke is spinning.  I would first try to unthread the center while  pressing the domed cover to one side to jam the center nipple in place. I think this unfortunately is an "If at first you don't succeed get a hammer" situation.

Comment: This package from HD shows the nipple below the yoke and a nut above as I described above. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Brass-Screw-Off-with-Collar-Loop-Kit-81755/306198188?

Comment: It's just caught on the screw threads. They're rarely perfectly spaced, so there's some lateral force applied to the trim plate. Or it's stuck to the paint. Pull.

Comment: might be stuck in the paint, or against the screw threads; give it a sharp whack with a wooden spoon to loosen it.

Answer (score 1):

BE SURE POWER IS OFF BEFORE PROCEEDING!

The [page here](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/wiring/mounting-light-fixtures) has this image:

[image: mounting]

I believe you just need to pull or work the decorative fixture base away from the mounting bracket.

Sometimes the base sticks to the ceiling and other times it's hung up on the bolts.  Some gentle persuasion usually does the trick.

Comment: I would lead with your final paragraph. The rest, while useful, is peripheral and probably understood. Also, the image is deceiving. It's the wrong fixture type. Then it would get my vote.